# Which type of http request should I use if I need pass a variable to server but the query is a SELECT?

Tags: javascript, php, rest

I have a blog of cooking recipes, in this blog the users signed up can read the posts of other users. I would a view default setting: In home page can read only the posts that have the same city of the user that has logged. To do this, I pass a variable to server that contains the id of the user, and this variable is used to do a query to recover the name of the city. When I retrieve this city's name I can the query (`SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE city = '$cityUser' ecc.`) to display all posts in home page.

This blog is based to RESTful service model.

JavaScript code to create a connection with server:

```
      function printAllPosts() {
        var data = {};
        data.id_user = idUser;
        var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.onload = function(){document.getElementById("ajaxres").innerHTML = oReq.responseText;};
        oReq.open("post", "api_printAllPosts.php/recipes/", true);
        oReq.send(jsondata);
      }
```

The php code to get the HTTP method, path and body of the request is:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

If in `oReq.open` the **http request type is "post"** everything works properly and the idUser is passed to server, if in `oReq.open` the **http request type is "get"** it not works.

If I pass data to the server and connect with it with the "post" method even though I am making a read-only request and therefore a select query, am I respecting the RESTful service or do I have to implement another design methodology to implement the "get" method?

Comment: `php://input` reads the raw request body; GET parameters are not part of the body. And with `oReq.send(jsondata)` you are not even sending your data in the first place, if the request method is GET, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send: _“send() accepts an optional parameter which lets you specify the request's body; this is primarily used for requests such as PUT. If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to null.”_

Comment: @Francesco, are you familiar with RESTFUL pattern for HTTP request?

Comment: I have to send data to the server and then the server makes only SELECT queries. Normally the http GET method should be used for SELECT queries, but if I used it I could not pass data, in this case the user id. If I use the POST method, I still respect the characteristics of the RESTful service?

Comment: _“but if I used it I could not pass data”_ - well, that’s because you are doing it wrong … If you want to make a GET request, then create a proper query string and append it to the URL. And then read the passed parameter in PHP using the default mechanism made for that, `$_GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally apis will use `GET` for reading data from an API. Conceptually, `GET` means 'Give me the representation for the uri'. GET requests should not have bodies.

Here's some examples of uris

```
http://api.example/recipes - Give me all recipes
http://api.example/recipes?city=Toronto - Give me all recipes from Toronto(?)
http://api.example/recipes?q=tomato - Give me all recipes that use tomatoes
```